# How to use de.entropia.can package in pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to use this github repo: https://github.com/entropia/libsocket-can-java in pom.xml file. I couldn't find any maven dependency for this github repo. I added jitpack repository and maven dependency to pom file by following this link: https://jitpack.io/p/entropia/libsocket-can-java. Here is my code:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.entropia</groupId>
    <artifactId>libsocket-can-java</artifactId>
    <version>4433bb7</version>
</dependency>
```

where 4433bb7 is the latest commit number. I get this error when I try to build:

```
Missing artifact com.github.entropia:libsocket-can-java:jar:4433bb7

Could not resolve dependencies for projec: Failure to find com.github.entropia:libsocket-can-java:jar:4433bb7 in https://jitpack.io was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I tried with bundle versions: 0.1.0, 1.0.0 still no luck. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Added latest snapshot version info. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue with the specific version. try latest snapshot:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.entropia</groupId>
        <artifactId>libsocket-can-java</artifactId>
        <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried `master-SNAPSHOT` as you mentioned. I'm still getting same error:

`Failure to find com.github.entropia:libsocket-can-java:jar:master-4433bb7a97-1 in https://jitpack.io was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced`

Comment: it means `jitpack.io ` repo does not have the jar. I am not sure, if `jitpack` repo is reliable. While working with automatic builds `<branch name>_SNAPSHOT` always points to last SNAPSHOT build. Ideally for this project, there must be a last SNAPSHOT release, which seems not available through `jitpack`

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!